Same queue for transfers vs separate queue on same queue family
I'm having trouble with writing my code to cover all the possibilities for the different hardware. If I want to transfer data to the GPU, to have all bases covered it would go something like this:
if HAS_DEDICATED_TRANSFER_QUEUE_FAMILY
code path 1

else if HAS_SEPARATE_TRANSFER_QUEUE_ON_ANOTHER_FAMILY
code path 2

else if HAS_SEPARATE_TRANSFER_QUEUE_ON_THE GRAPHICS FAMILY
code path 3

else
Operate on the assumption that you'll be submitting transfers on the same queue.

This is way way too complicated to manage. I am intending on simplifying to the following:
if HAS_DEDICATED_TRANSFER_QUEUE_FAMILY
code path 1
else 
Assume you submit transfers on the single graphics queue.

The reasoning is that I don't believe that having another a separate queue on the same family is of any benefit. Is this a true assumption?
However what if it doesn't have a dedicated transfer queue family but it does have a compute family that's also capable of transfer, then you probably should use that one, because it's a separate family (albeit not a dedicated transfer one).
